# Can I constrain a route parameter to a certain type in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, constraints, mvccontrib

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search",                                               // Route name
    "Search/{affiliateId}",                                 // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Syndication", action = "Search" }   // Parameter defaults
);
```

Is there a way I can ensure "affiliateId" is a valid Guid?  I'm using MVCContrib elsewhere in my site and I'm fairly it provides a way to implement this kind of constraint.... I just don't know what it is!

Comment: So you want to make sure the affiliateId is a Guid before matching the route, correct? Or are you wanting to ensure affiliateId is Guid before executing the Search action?

Comment: I only want the route to match if affiliateId is a Guid, yes.  If it's not a guid, then the Search action shouldn't get executed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write regex constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search",                                               // Route name
    "Search/{affiliateId}",                                 // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Syndication", action = "Search" },   // Parameter defaults
    new { affiliateId = "SOME REGEX TO TEST GUID FORMAT" } // constraints
);
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks.  I was hoping for something a little less brittle though.

Comment: @Paul Suart: If `affiliateId` is just a numeric parameter, than your regex is simply `"\d"` and you're good to go. Why do you think it's brittle?

Comment: It's a guid, so the regex is more complex than "\d".  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, doesn't seem so complex to me. First result in google: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=regex+valid+guid&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this. I fear it would cause some confusion if you mistakenly used the wrong type for the `affiliateId` parameter in one of your action methods.

Comment: I don't think it's uncommon to constrain a route to a certain structure.  As another poster states, I could use a regex which is a known and documented way of ensuring the route is only matched when the url is of a certain format.  I'm a nice guy so no -1 :)

Comment: Ok after seeing your clarification above I believe I misunderstood you. Are you looking to make two routes, like `Search\{affiliateId}` and `Search\{query}`? If so I think the regex route is best. Alternatively your Search action could accept a string parameter and then call the appropriate code for searching vs affiliates.