# How to add a constraint to a route parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, routes, constraints

I'd like to add a constraint to a route parameter that I have. The route pattern is:

```
{region}/{controller}/{action}
```

where `{region}` should only be `UK` or `US`.

How can I do this? Is there a regex I can apply here, or some other means of defining this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I constrain a route parameter to a certain type in ASP.net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928600/can-i-constrain-a-route-parameter-to-a-certain-type-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked before.  See:

[Constraint Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928600/can-i-constrain-a-route-parameter-to-a-certain-type-in-asp-net-mvc)

In essence, use Regular Expressions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search",                                               // Route name
    "Search/{affiliateId}",                                 // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Syndication", action = "Search" },   // Parameter defaults
    new { affiliateId = "SOME REGEX TO TEST GUID FORMAT" } // constraints
);
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I don't know the regex. Can you fill me in?

Comment: @DaveDev - The regex you're looking for is "^UK|US$"

Comment: @DaveDev: check out http://www.regexlib.com or other regex sites for **tons** of useful examples....